# Applying pear.php.net patches

Tags: php, pear, patch

During a pecl package installation, i got the error,

```
Download of "pecl/pecl_http" succeeded, but it is not a valid package archive
Error: cannot download "pecl/pecl_http"
```

I found a solution on a blog [here](http://cweiske.de/tagebuch/pear-php-5.5.htm), it requires me to apply the patch file available in, https://pear.php.net/bugs/bug.php?id=19746&edit=12&patch=archive_tar_php55.patch&revision=1355241213

But i don't have any idea on how to apply that. It would be helpful if someone explains me the procedure. Help please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ pear info archive_tar|head -n1
ABOUT PEAR.PHP.NET/ARCHIVE_TAR-1.3.8
$ cd `pear config-get php_dir`
$ wget -O /tmp/archive.diff "https://pear.php.net/bugs/patch-download.php?id=19746&patch=archive_tar_php55.patch&revision=1355241213"
$ patch -p1 < /tmp/archive.diff
$ pear upgrade-all
... works
```

Source: http://cweiske.de/tagebuch/pear-php-5.5.htm